# CRC32 with JAMCRC

Tags: crc32

I have come across the site with JS which does with many input values which matches as expected.  I am not finding any Java code or C# with same implementation to return same result.
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

Radio button selected: "CRC32"
predefined list box: "CRC32_JAMCRC"
CRC Input data selected: "Bytes"

Input value: 05dccb78faf7aff4f628a95d3d5b166986dbc3eea611ae02d3c63e6d203232f517f7c9fa5b6acb50d9df12e1e54f7fe1cd943fa713c4ce12143db6745693315d5e0de5ce492b628c483549b9ccc8ebb89f2df25b76f4b7964fa193bac9c13c5d4a6b941dbad7a1e0c8f1e578e75f797aa65224f68e11bcf7b45db428ed29078a

CRC Output: 0x3C2E4892

Can anyone point the way it need to be done in C#?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 7):

The "JAMCRC" is simply the bitwise-not of the standard CRC-32. A quick search turned up [this](https://github.com/force-net/Crc32.NET), and I am sure you can find many implementations of CRC-32. Then you just take the not (~) of the result to get the JAMCRC.